# How to make DropdownButton menu width to fit text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dropdown

I want to have a dropdown button that has a width based on the menu text length. The dropdown arrow does not have any additional spacing between text.
Like this:

[image]

Currently, I am getting this:

[image]

My dropdown button arrow is positioned based on the longest text.

My code:

```
Widget dropdownList(){
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButton<Location>(
          value: _selectedValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
          iconSize: 30,
          underline: SizedBox(),
          onChanged: (Location? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return locationList.map((Location value) {
              return Container(
                child: Text(
                  value.name,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 30,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
          items: locationList.map<DropdownMenuItem<Location>>((Location value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<Location>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value.name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i am not a flutter  dev but in css display:inline-block for the text would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) there is a property for DropDownButton called isExpanded:

```
isExpanded → bool
Set the dropdown's inner contents to horizontally fill its parent. [...]
final
```

so just set:

```
isExpanded = true;
```

Comment: Hi I do not want to follow its parent but I want the dropdown menu to be the length of its displayed text

Comment: I thing you should create a seperated dropdownbutton for each one of the items. or change the source code.

Comment: I took your advise as an idea and used a different widget to achieve it. Don't think via DropDownButton is doable. Thanks!

Comment: @Huiting Would you mind sharing which widget you used to achieve this? I am facing a similar dilemma and cannot figure this out.

Comment: @Igor Hi I had to give up using `DropdownButton`. Instead a created a container with those layout and onPressed opened a new page with the list of items.